# Pass parameters to GeoServer WMS parametric SQL view?

Tags: geoserver, wms, parameters, mapproxy

I would like to configure MapProxy to retrieve an SQL Parametric View based Layer from a GeoServer instance. I can successfully get one layer with the following source:

```
services:
  demo:
  wms:
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS
      abstract: MapProxy WMS

layers:
  - name: temperature
    title: Hourly temperature
    sources: [temp_cache]

caches:
  temp_cache:
    grids: [webmercator]
    sources: [mysource]

sources:
  mysource:
    type: wms
    req:
      url: "https://example.com/geoserver/myserver/wms"
      layers: temperature
      viewparams: YEAR:2022;MONTH:6;DAY:10;HOUR:12;
      transparent: true

grids:
   webmercator:
     base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
```

Good, now I would like to be able to modify mysource so that I can dynamically define the values of the `viewparams` attribute. In the documentation of MapProxy
what looks like to be a possible solution is to use dimensions. So I've modified the configuration like that:

```
services:
  demo:
  wms:
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS
      abstract: MapProxy WMS
  wmts:
    restful_template: "/{Layer}/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{TileMatrixSet}
      /{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.{Format}"

layers:
  - name: temperature
    title: Hourly temperature
    sources: [temp_cache]
    dimensions:
      year:
        values:
          - 2021
          - 2022
          - 2023
      month:
        values:
          - 1
          - 2
          - 3
          ...
      day:
        values:
          - 1
          - 2
          - 3
          ...
      hour:
        values:
          - 0
          - 1
          - 2
          ...

caches:
  temp_cache:
    grids: [webmercator]
    sources: [mysource]
    disable_storage: true

sources:
  mysource:
    type: wms
    req:
      url: "https://example.com/geoserver/myserver/wms"
      layers: temperature
      viewparams: YEAR:{year};MONTH:{month};DAY:{day};HOUR:{hour};
      transparent: true
    forward_req_params: ["year", "month", "day", "hour"]

grids:
   webmercator:
     base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
```

Parameters `["year", "month", "day", "hour"]` are now transmitted to MapProxy but how should I modify my sources config so that they are used to fill the `viewparams`
property.

I've tested different syntaxes to try that parameters are taken into consideration, but none of them is working. Is it possible to do that?